# Get the SPListItems using SPList.GetItems(SPQuery)

Tags: spquery

I have a requirement of filtering the data from the SPList (ex:20000 SPListItems) and I bind it to the radgrid.  I want to get first 200 and next 200 of every page click in the radgrid.

This is my code:

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"SiteCollection\"";
query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'><Value Type='Text'>s</Value></Eq></Where>";
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title'>";
query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
query.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Strict;
splist.EnableThrottling = false;
query.RowLimit = 2000;
 do
                        {
                            SPListItemCollection myItems = splist.GetItems(query);
                            if (dt == null || dt.Rows.Count <= 0)
                                dt = myItems.GetDataTable();
                            else
                                dt.Merge(myItems.GetDataTable());
                            query.ListItemCollectionPosition = myItems.ListItemCollectionPosition;
                        }
                        while (query.ListItemCollectionPosition != null);
```

How do I paginate the results?

Comment: This question is borderline off topic per the [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)  we do not accept questions about commercial, third-party products. You may want to ask your question on Telerik's support site: http://www.telerik.com/support.aspx

Answer (score 4):

1) You don't need the `ViewAttributes` node in your example, as you're targeting a single list.

2) Your pages will be 2000 items long with your current `RowLimit` attribute

3) You have the throttle mode set to `Strict` when infact you disable throttling the line after - try it without these settings omitted and logged in as Admin first.

4) Have you tried a simplified version without the DataTable first, from the MSDN page on the `ListItemCollectionPosition` property? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.listitemcollectionposition.aspx

Comment: Hi james, Thanks for your reply, clearly i explain my scenario, kindly give the solution for this. 1. i have 20000 records in my sharepoint custom list like List1, List2,List3.......List20000. 2. i want to get the list items using SPList.GetItems(SPQuery), my list items result count is 10000. 3. in this 10000 items i don't want to show all 10000 items, i need to show only first 200 items, and next 200 items and next 200 items, is it possible, kindly give the solution fo this